# How to add an assembly reference programmatically

Tags: .net, build, reference, compilation

Here is my scenario: we are planning to automate the deltabuild process, meaning I need to create  a tool to facilitate this deltabuild process.

What I need to do is to compile only those files that have changes in it. How can I programmatically add an assembly reference to reference  other dll's so I don't need to compile that other dll's? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you referring to adding to your solution? Is this .NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can introspect the project file(s) and add or remove the project references based on the code files that have changed.  This assumes, of course, that those code files that have changed are not dependent on the references you are removing.  If you need to reference those other assemblies because your code files depend upon them, then you will need the references to build.

Comment: Okay sorry for the misleading title of "adding references" but I mean is it possible to change the assembly reference to point to an already compiled dll(programatically) so that when i built that particular project,  we dont need to compile those unchanged files.

Comment: Also how can you do the adding or removing of refrences programatically

Comment: Yes, you can edit the project file.  The project file is just an xml file that has the path to the assemblies written out in text form.  I was suggesting you change this text to point to the explicit DLLs on the harddrive instead of having them reference the other projects in the solution.  You can write a program that will detect which files have changed and to update the references accordingly.  After this, your program can call msbuild on the solution containing the new project files.

Comment: Wow Thankyou very much ill try opening the project file as an xml. using the XNL reader class then edit from there. Also I will be using the checksum of each files to detect the changes. Again Thanks much This will help me alot doing the deltabuild tool.